# I have an API method which has one of its parameters bound; can I bypass this parameter binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, parameters, asp.net-core-webapi

Example:

my Method:

```
public async Task<dto> MethodName([PropertyBinding(allow:true)]string p1)
{
}
```

I have a scenario where I do not want to allow property binding while calling this API. Is there a way where I can change the parameter 'allow' to false while calling the API.

Comment: I don't know if there is any way to change it. But conceptually speaking this seems to be a very bad idea. You have declaratively told the compiler to enforce some constraints on your method and now you are telling that you have changed your mind. Better to write a different method instead.

Comment: Maybe you should create a second public method without the binding (and different name) and both methods then call some "inner" private method to do the same, but with different defaults.